# How have IDE type awareness with app-module-path in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm in a node environment where they are using app-module-path so that the requires can always be written from a base path.

So all path's can be: `const something = require('/api/something')` instead of having to back down the folder structure with something like: `const something = require('../../api/something)`.

Without the exact path, VSCode says all types are of type any.  This means functionality like 'go to definition' won't work.

Is there a way to configure VSCode to address this?

Answer (score 3):

After some more searching I found this can be done by using a jsconfig.son file with the following settings.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
          "*",
          "app/*"
        ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
      "app/**/*.js"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue but with Webstorm. I'm trying to find a similar configuration but haven't succeeded so far.