# Is it possible for vscode to auto-import paths in a non-relative way when using app-module-path library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm using [app-module-path](https://github.com/patrick-steele-idem/app-module-path-node), for resolving require statements without having to explicitly provide the relative path to the module. But vscode cant recognize the module since it's not relative path. I had tried using `jsconfig` by following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082341/how-have-ide-type-awareness-with-app-module-path-in-visual-studio-code). I created the jsconfig in the root of my project. But the path resolution done by vscode conflicted with `app-module-path`, since vscode adds a `server/` prefix before all paths. What changes should I make to `jsconfig.json` inorder to make it work with `app-module-path`?

#### Context

```
.
├── jsconfig.json
├── package.json
├── server
│   ├── app.js --------> here I set the app-module-path
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── helpers
│   │   ├── email
│   │   │   ├── fetch.js
│   │   └── urlparser.js
│   └── services
│       └── github
│           └── index.js-> i want import "helpers/email/fetch" from here, not "server/helpers/email/fetch"
└── yarn.lock
```

With `app-module-path` set in `app.js` in base of `server`, I am able to do the following from `server/services/github/index.js`:-

```js
const {emailFetch} = require("helpers/email/fetch"); // Note: I cant use the "server/" prefix before "helpers" since app-module-path will lead to error
const {emailFetch} = require("server/helpers/email/fetch"); // This is how vscode auto-imports
```

This is how I have registered the `app-module-path` in `app.js`:-

```js
require("app-module-path").addPath(__dirname);
```

With the following `jsconfig.json`, vscode gives intellisense, signature help, go to definition etc even if the path is `helpers/email/fetch`(without `server/` prefix). **But how can i make vscode auto-import or fix the `require` statements, in way such that it doesn't add `server` prefix before all import statements?** Should I use some vscode-extension for doing this job?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*",
        "server/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "server/**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just posting my answer too over here, so that someone else finds it useful. Currently I have made it to work by changing `baseUrl` into `"server"` and removing `"server/*"` from `paths`, in `jsconfig.json`. With this I get correct auto-imports + change in import paths while I move files around too. Do post your answers if you know to do this is in a better way. Cheers!

Comment: This is great solution for VS Code NodeJS applications